# Opencv Unhandled exception in contour.exe

Tags: opencv, contour, unhandled-exception

My code in *OpenCV* works well up until when I want to find *contours*:

```
findContours(src, contours,hierarchy, CV_RETR_TREE, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);
```

then I keep getting the following error:

> "Unhandled exception at 0x773e3e28 in Contour.exe: Microsoft C++
>   exception: cv::Exception at memory location 0x002ff3ac.."

Do you have any idea about this error?

My full code is below.

Thanks

```
Mat src=Mat(100,200,CV_64F),newimg;
vector<vector<Point>> contours;
vector<Vec4i> hierarchy;

for (int i=25;i<80;i++)
    for(int j=25;j<80;j++)
        src.at<double>(i,j)=1;
imshow("img",src);
waitKey(0);

findContours(src, contours,hierarchy, CV_RETR_TREE, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);
```

Comment: findContours accepts only CV_8UC1 images (in particular cases also CV_32SC1). You're passing a CV_64F instead

Comment: You generally apply an edge detector (E.G. Canny) to an image, and then take the canny output and feed it into the edge detector. The function findContours accepts a CV_8UC1 image to look for contours.

Comment: @Masoud then check that you're not using release libs in debug mode, or viceversa

Comment: @Miki I tried both release and debug modes. I'm now trying the opencv's example here: [http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/shapedescriptors/find_contours/find_contours.html](opencv contour) and still have problem with `findcontour` but this time the error is :   **Windows has triggered a breakpoint in Contour.exe.

This may be due to a corruption of the heap, which indicates a bug in Contour.exe or any of the DLLs it has loaded.

This may also be due to the user pressing F12 while Contour.exe has focus.

The output window may have more diagnostic information.**

Comment: @Miki Thanks a lot Miki and Chris for being responsive. I am running the exact example [here](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/shapedescriptors/find_contours/find_contours.html) except that I read the image inside the `main()` as `src = imread("C:\\Users\\Masoud\\Desktop\\fish.jpg");` and get the error I mentioned in the comment above DLL, F12,...). Also, I'm running it in the release mode as I get MSVCP110D.dll problem! such a pain :-)

Comment: what version of Visual Studio are you using?

Comment: @Masoud What version of opencv are you using, what compiler (and version) are you using, and what compiler flags are you using?

Comment: @Masoud Also, not that it should matter, but what version of windows are you running?

Comment: OpenCV 3.00  and Visual Studio 2010 running everything on Win32 (my laptop is 64 though). Windows 10.

Comment: @Masoud Win32 of what windows? (7/8/8.1/NT/10/etc)

Comment: Please show the library directory of OpenCV (where you find the libs). It should be something like D:\libs\opencv-300\build\x86\vc10\lib

Comment: Additional Lib. directories  --> **$(OPENCV_DIR)\lib**   where       **OPENCV_DIR** is  **C:\opencv3\build\x86\vc11**. I've also included opencv_ts300.lib   and  opencv_world300.lib for the "release" mode.

Comment: There it is.. your problem! Either use Visual Studio 2012, or recompile OpenCV using VS 2010! Or change to dir C:\opencv3\build\x86\vc10 if you have it already

Comment: Thanks so much Miki! I'll rebuild it with VS2010 or I'll upgrade my VS. Many thanks again :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quoting from OpenCV documentation about [findContours](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html?#findcontours)

> **image** – Source, an **8-bit single-channel** image. Non-zero pixels are treated as 1’s. Zero pixels remain 0’s, so the image is treated as binary . You can use compare() , inRange() , threshold() , adaptiveThreshold() , Canny() , and others to create a binary image out of a grayscale or color one. The function modifies the image while extracting the contours. If mode equals to CV_RETR_CCOMP or CV_RETR_FLOODFILL, the input can also be a 32-bit integer image of labels (CV_32SC1).

You can adjust your code converting your `CV_64FC1` image to a `CV_8UC1` like:

```
...
Mat1b img8u;
src.convertTo(img8u, CV_8U);

vector<vector<Point>> contours;
vector<Vec4i> hierarchy;

findContours(img8u, contours, hierarchy, CV_RETR_TREE, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);
...
```

---

In addition, from the comments turns out that you are using Visual Studio 2010, but linking OpenCV built with msvc11 (Visual Studio 2012).

You need either to use Visual Studio 2012, or recompile OpenCV with msvc10 (Visual Studio 2010). If you decide to upgrade VS, you can go directly to VS2013 (and link to vc12), or to VS2015 (but you need to recompile OpenCV as well).

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is you are giving "findContours" a CV_64F image when it requires a CV_8UC1 image. You generally pass findContours the output of an edge detector. (E.G. Canny).

If you modify your code to the following you can find the contours in an image after filtering it through Canny.

```
Mat src=Mat(100,200,CV_64F),newimg;
Mat tCannyMat;
vector<vector<Point>> contours;
vector<Vec4i> hierarchy;

for (int i=25;i<80;i++)
    for(int j=25;j<80;j++)
        src.at<double>(i,j)=1;
imshow("img",src);
waitKey(0);

int lowThreshold = 0x3f;//This is the single value threshold
int ratio = 3;//This is the ratio to apply for the entire pixel
int kernel_size = 3;//This is the canny kernel size

//You can use your own edge detector/a different one here if you wish.
//Canny merely serves to give a working example. 
cv::Canny( src, tCannyMat, lowThreshold, lowThreshold*ratio, kernel_size );

findContours(tCannyMat, contours,hierarchy, CV_RETR_TREE, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);
```

Comment: Most obfuscated `Canny` call I've ever seen :D. Also you don't need Canny to make it works.

Comment: @Miki Haha, it was copied directly from the project I was working on when I saw this question. (I have the various values dynamically assigned, but I decided to keep the variables as it is a nice way to manipulate the function. )

Comment: Thanks guys but still keep getting the same error even when I convert it to CV_8UC1 and use Canny (or even without Canny)!

Comment: @Miki Ah ok. Any time I am dealing with pixel values I just always prefer to write it in base 16. The value of 0x3f itself is ambiguous. (Once again originating from a default value for my project)